# Merge local changes to newly created fork

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-fork

I have a repo on github in which I have cloned on my local machine and made edits and changes without committing them.

I then created a fork of that repo realizing this was the better way to go about things.

How can I merge my existing changes on my local repo to the newly created fork?

Comment: If you haven't committed them, you cannot merge because there's nothing to merge.  Commit your changes.

Comment: Once you've committed, you can specify the remote to which you want to push changes as an argument to `git push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit your changes locally. Lets call this 'A'.
Pull the forked branch from Github onto your local machine. Lets call this 'B'.
Merge A and B locally. Call the result 'C'.
Push 'C' back up to Github.